# Removing exact instances of elements in one list from another

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods

Basically, here's the problem statement:

> Given an `IEnumerable<T> source` and an `IEnumerable<T> exceptions`, return an `IEnumerable<T> result` which contains all of `source`, without `exceptions`, only omitting exact instances of a value. I.e.: if a value appears twice in `source`, but once in `exceptions`, then `result` will have that value exactly one time.

Let's take an example:

Exception list:

```
{ 2, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Source list:

```
{ 2, 2, 2, 6 }
```

Result:

```
{ 2, 6 }
```

---

Code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ExceptExact<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> exceptions)
{
    var tExceptions = new List<T>();
    tExceptions.AddRange(exceptions);

    var result = new List<T>();

    foreach (var el in source)
    {
        if (tExceptions.Contains(el))
        {
            tExceptions.RemoveAt(tExceptions.IndexOf(el));
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(el);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

Usage:

> ```
> var a = new List<int> { 2, 3, 5, 4, 2 };
> var b = new List<int> { 2, 2, 2, 6 };
>
> var c = b.ExceptExact(a);
> var d = a.ExceptExact(b);
>
> Console.WriteLine("A: { " + string.Join(", ", a) + " }");
> Console.WriteLine("B: { " + string.Join(", ", b) + " }");
> Console.WriteLine("C: { " + string.Join(", ", c) + " }");
> Console.WriteLine("D: { " + string.Join(", ", d) + " }");
> ```

Output:

> ```
> A: { 2, 3, 5, 4, 2 }
> B: { 2, 2, 2, 6 }
> C: { 2, 6 }
> D: { 3, 5, 4 }
> ```

Comment: Could it be that you interchanged source and exceptions in your initial example? The number 6 does not occur in the source but in the result.

Comment: @MartinR Absolutely! Fixed, thanks for catching that! :)

Comment: whats the logic behind the name tExceptions?

Comment: @pm100 `tExceptions` is a temporary list of the `exceptions` parameter, because I cannot delete values from the input parameter.

Comment: so 't' prefix means temporary? Arent all stack variables temporary?

Comment: @pm100 It's to indicate that it's a temporary replacement of `exceptions`, what name would you prefer?

Comment: tempExceptions. I am so used to the common (misused, horrible) hungarian prefix system like nCount, pString, etc . Thats what this looks like

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Additional to the valid point from Rick Davin:

1) You can drop the `Contains` because `IndexOf` returns -1 if the item is not contained.

2) You could use yield to get rid of the additional list

---

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ExceptExact<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> exceptions)
{
    var tExceptions = exceptions.ToList();

    foreach (var el in source)
    {
        var index = tExceptions.IndexOf(el);
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            tExceptions.RemoveAt(index);
            continue;
        }
        yield return el;
    }
}
```

---

After taking a look to MSDN ([List.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx)), I figured out that there is even a simpler way:

> Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the List.
>
> Returns true if item is successfully removed; otherwise, false.This method
>   also returns false if item was not found in the List.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ExceptExact<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> exceptions)
{
    var tExceptions = exceptions.ToList();
    return source.Where(el => !tExceptions.Remove(el));
}
```

Comment: I always forget about `yield return`...thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: You are welcome... I found another simpler solution that doesn't even require the yield ;).

Comment: This is a nice trick with the remove ;-)

Answer (score 5):

It's a short enough method that there's not much to comment upon.  You could shorten these two lines:

```
var tExceptions = new List<T>();
tExceptions.AddRange(exceptions);
```

Into just one:

```
var tExceptions = exceptions.ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider the case where `source` and `exceptions` each consist of one value, repeated `n` times, e.g.

```
source = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 1000000)
```

and

```
exceptions = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 1000000)
```

Your algorithm and JanDotNet's algorithm will run in \$O(n^2)\$ time.

We can reduce this to \$O(n)\$ time by doing the following:

- Create a dictionary containing the count of each distinct value in `exceptions`
- For each value in `values`:

  - If the dictionary contains a non-zero count for `value`:

    - Reduce the count of `value` in the dictionary by one
  - Otherwise:

    - Yield return `value`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to preserve the order of the elements a simple LINQ query like this one would give you the same results:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ExceptExact<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> x, 
        IEnumerable<T> y) 
    {
        return
            x
            .GroupBy(n => n)
            .Select(g => 
                g.Skip(y.Where(m => m.Equals(g.Key)).Count()))
            .SelectMany(n => n);
   } 
}
```

Comment: +1 for an alternative approach. However IMHO it is more difficult to read than the foreach loop.

Comment: I do want to preserve element order...

Comment: I wouldn't call this LINQ query "simple". More like "wtf is going on here" :)

Comment: @NikitaB it all depends on how good you know LINQ. Theoretically every query that contains more than a single where/select isn't simple.

Comment: @t3chb0t, it is more about how good your query conveys your intent. I saw larger LINQ queries which were way easier to read. The fact that you replaced good variable names with a bunch of x's, y's and m's does not help either.

Answer (score 1):

I guess am late to the party !!!! Most of the improvements have been suggested by @JanDotNet, @mjolka, @Rick Davin and @t3chb0t. There are two things I would like to add here is

1. There is no check to ensure the **source** and **exception** enumerables are not empty before proceeding with the other computations
2. I'm not criticising your approach but I believe there are smarter ways to achieve your objective here. I was a little surprised no one suggested using Except for this approach as it is more robust(can be applied to string and int)

The signature for Except is

> `Enumerable.Except<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>, IEqualityComparer<TSource>)`

you can use the IEqualityComparer to create a custom Equality Comparer e.g [Why Enumerable.Except() Might Not Work the Way You Might Expect](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2011/08/08/why-enumerableexcept-might-not-work-the-way-you-might-expect). Note, using the default **Except**  may result in your duplicate being removed e.g

```
Exception list:

{ 2, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Source list:

{ 2, 2, 2, 6 }

var result = source.Except(exceptions)
```

> The result would give {6}.

The implementation of Except ensures duplicates are removed as a set class is used for the implementation. Hence the second Enumerable is added to the set and duplicates are removed when the first Enumerable is added. That's why 2 got removed giving {6). A snippet of the implementation is given below.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    if (first == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
    }
    if (second == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
    }
    return ExceptIterator<TSource>(first, second, comparer);
}

private static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first,
IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    Set<TSource> iteratorVariable0 = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource local in second)
    {
        iteratorVariable0.Add(local);
    }
    foreach (TSource iteratorVariable1 in first)
    {
        if (!iteratorVariable0.Add(iteratorVariable1))
        {
            continue;
        }
        yield return iteratorVariable1;
    }
}
```

Note: This question has been answered by Marius Schulz in his github page [Without method-EXTRALINQ](https://github.com/mariusschulz/ExtraLINQ/blob/master/src/app/ExtraLINQ/IEnumerable/Without.cs)  by extending the ExceptIterator to a new Iterator called WithoutIterator which uses a hashset and linq to behave exactly the way you would want Except method to function.